# Wanted: .Net helper to work with url paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to do some work on the urls that look like this:

```
https://www.myurl.com/deep/path/file.rdp?q=true
```

I need to change it into:

```
https://www.myurl.com/deep/z.asmx
```

The path can be deeper.

When I'm working with files I use `System.IO.Path` to do modifications.

Is there a good way to work with url paths without doing a lot of string manipulations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var uri = new Uri("https://www.myurl.com/deep/path/file.rdp?q=true");
var parts = uri.Segments;
```

parts will be `/` `deep/` `path/` `file.rdp`

Comment: Should I put the segments on a stack and pop them?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker I think you only need `Segments[1]`

Comment: The path can be way deeper than this ;-)

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker it is an `string[]` no need to use any structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sResult = 
    Regex.Replace("http://site.com/page1.php?par=true", @"(?<=/)[^/]*$", "z.asmx");
```

Regular expression `"(?<=/)[^/]*$"` is said to be "find *page1.php?par=true*" and then the method `Regex.Replace` replaces the found part with "z.asmx".

Also you can use `strToModify.Split('/').Last();` for finding last part.